# "Missed call" notification in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, notifications, call

I am using CallKit with Agora video calling. Everything is working ok; making a call, answering, canceling a call... When a user does not answer a call, it is showing up in the recent call list as "missed call", but the user is not getting a notification of a missed call.

How and where do I add a notification to show that the user missed a call? I want the missed call to show as a notification (like when getting a message, calendar alert, missed call from native phone...)

Any thoughts or suggestions? any direction would be greatly appreciated.

I've been trying to see if the local UserNotifications would work; but seems too complicated to trigger it in the background of the application. Or maybe that's the way to do it? I can't find anything in CallKit that would add the missed call as a notification ..